# How to interpret array indices in which() output?

Tags: r

I'm very new to R, so this is very much a beginner's question.

I'm trying to read/interpret the returned matrix from a `which(x , arr.ind = TRUE)` command.

The data I'm using is:

`qux <- array(data = c(10,5,1,4,7,4,3,3,1,3,4,3,1,7,8,3,7,3), dim = c(3, 2, 3))`

I run `which()` while filtering for values lower than 3 and tell the `which()` function to return array indices, using `arr.ind = TRUE`.

```
> which(qux<3, arr.ind = TRUE)

     dim1 dim2 dim3
[1,]    3    1    1
[2,]    3    1    2
[3,]    1    1    3
```

I would assume the numbers in the left most column indicate the rows (of which there are 3 in the array), the other three columns to the right indicate the dimensions (of which there are also 3), and the numbers that make up the matrix are the column numbers.

However, this can't be true since there are only two columns in all the dimensions of the array, whereas there's three 3's in the matrix.

Please help me understand this elementary part of R.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `qux` is a three dimensional array with exactly three values that are 1, the rest are greater than three.

The output you see gives the positions for those values that are less than three

```
which(qux<3, arr.ind = TRUE)
#      dim1 dim2 dim3
# [1,]    3    1    1
# [2,]    3    1    2
# [3,]    1    1    3
```

and

```
qux[3,1,1]
# [1] 1
qux[3,1,2]
# [1] 1
qux[1,1,3]
# [1] 1
```

so each row of the `which()` matrix gives you the index for each of the three dimensions in your original array.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! Can you explain your last sentence a little bit more? 

I understand how the indices in the `[ ]` operator relate to the `qux` array, but I don't understand how the `which()` matrix relates these indices. For example, what does the top left number 3 indicate? the number of ... ?

Comment: Oh I get it now! dim1, dim2, dim3 stand for rows, columns, layers. Thanks!